# Integration of Instagram in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to post a photo to Instagram through my app. I am using UIDocumentInteractionController according to [INstagram guidlines](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/)

in my .h file

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController;
```

in my .m file

```
NSString *fileToOpen = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0192"  ofType:@"jpg"];
fileToOpen = [fileToOpen substringToIndex:[fileToOpen length] - 3];
 fileToOpen=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ig",fileToOpen];
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
NSLog(@"%@",fileToOpen);
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    //imageToUpload is a file path with .ig file extension
    /*UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"" 
                          message:@"Can open app!" 
                          delegate:self  
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    */



    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileToOpen]];
    self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
    self.documentInteractionController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Its a testing" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
```

is am missing something.??it is not working.

Comment: hey have you done this? i need your help for same

Comment: use this link http://www.albinopixel.com/blog/posting-to-instagram-from-your-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your photo ID or file URL is not correct here. I've done this successfully with the following code snippet:

in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *docDic;
```

also add the following delegate:

```
UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
```

in your .m file:

1. synthesize the docDic object
2. Write the following method:

   ```
   -(UIDocumentInteractionController *)setupControllerWithURL:(NSURL*)fileURL usingDelegate:(id<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>)interactionDelegate{
       UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
       interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
       return interactionController;
   }
   ```
3. Then add the following code snippet to your shareToInstagram function:

   NSString *fileToOpen = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0192" ofType:@"jpg"];

   fileToOpen = [fileToOpen substringToIndex:[fileToOpen length] - 3];

   fileToOpen=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.ig",fileToOpen];

   NSURL *instagramURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", fileToOpen]];

   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]){

   ```
   self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileToOpen]];
   ```

   self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";

   [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
   }

Hopefully it will help you. Best of luck. :-)